# addClass to div on scroll page jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, addclass

I guess I need help. I'm trying to work with jQuery and I don't know much, but I'm having this problem with the "color active" of the menu.

Here is an simplified version of my work: http://jsfiddle.net/paulakfleck/aZGKz/

Here is the whole work (complete): http://nartecrobotica.com.br/g4/

As you can see, when I click in the menu, the "active color" works, but when I scroll the page or open the page, do not.

I guess the big mistake is in this line:

`if($(window).scrollTop() == $("#g-4")){...}`

I put the #g-4 as an example, but isn't working too.

I try other answers at Stackoverflow, but I'm unable make that work.

Some light, please?

Comment: Yes, as you are comparing object with numeric value!

Comment: Oh.. do you know the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your menu to change as you scroll, you could try this:

```
$('.grid').each(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(this).position().top - ($(this).height() / 2)) {
        $('.myList a').removeClass('active');
        $('.myList a#menu' + $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1]).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Updated your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aZGKz/6/).

Comment: I used the #g-4 just how an example... I want when I scroll over the page, the "active color" change according to the specific div. Just like here: http://jalxob.com/cool-kitten/ (scroll the page to see what's happen to the menu color)

Answer (score 1):

are u looking for this ..

If yes then i am using `.offset().top` to compare.

one problem that was `$(window).scrollTop()` gives the scrollbar postion in integer and your divs position is fixed hence you need to do a range check before you apply the class.

[Check demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/aZGKz/4/)

Comment: Great! This one worked too, but he answered first, sorry : / but thanks!

Comment: @PaulaFleck dont be sorry magnus answer is faar better than mine.go with that]